# Translation of the work of Gauss where the fast Fourier transform algorithm first appeared

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, fourier-analysis, math-history, fast-fourier-transform

As far as I know, the fast Fourier transform algorithm first appeared in 1805 in "Theoria interpolationis methodo nova tractata", by Carl Friedrich Gauss. This work is available [in Latin](https://www.deutsche-digitale-bibliothek.de/item/VAK3TPRSI57PWW6OSOSWAU52CN7CNRJP), which, to say the least, I don't speak fluently.

**Would someone know if there is an English or French translation of this work?**

(If not, a Spanish, German or Italian version would already help me.)

Comment: Maybe useful [Gauss and the History of the Fast Fourier Transform](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.331.4791&rep=rep1&type=pdf) with ref to a partial translation into:  H.H. GOLDSTINE, [A History of Numerical Analysis from the 16th Through the 19th Century](https://books.google.it/books?id=r7ffBwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1977), page 249-253.

Comment: Dear @MauroALLEGRANZA, this already useful, indeed. The "translation" is a bit awkward, since it is more of a rephrasing, but it is already much better than no translation. Tanks!